# Laravel Adldap check connection

Tags: php, laravel

I have an Adldap login in my page.
I want to check server was avaliable or not.

When i try to login to my site, and AD Server was not avaliable i always got this error:

> AdldapException in Adldap.php line 376: Bind to Active Directory
>   failed. Check the login credentials and/or server details. AD said:
>   Can't contact LDAP server

What can i do? How can i catch this error.
Can i call `Adldap::authenticate($username, $password)` with timeout?

I hope someone can help me. I do not want to see laravel error, when i cant connect to AD Server.

This not work:

```
try {
      if (!Adldap::authenticate($username, $password))
           return view($page)->withErrors($this ->error_ActiveDirFailed);
    }
    catch (AdldapException $e) {
       dd($e);
    }
```

Thanks!